# login required : eclipse.tmatesoft.com every few minutes eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox

[image]

from ErrorLog
 - eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository Error Sat Sep 09 16:13:23 CST 2017
   Authentication failed for http://eclipse.tmatesoft.com/svnkit/1.8.x/.

How to remove this Plug-in?

Answer (score 13):

[Equinox p2](https://www.eclipse.org/equinox/p2/) is an important part of Eclipse and responsible for updating and installing. Instead of shooting the messenger, you probably want to stop  `eclipse.tmatesoft.com` (which [requires a login now](https://eclipse.tmatesoft.com/svnkit/1.8.x/)) being called:

1. Go to ***Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites***
2. **Uncheck** the checkbox of the entry with the location **`http://eclipse.tmatesoft.com/svnkit/1.8.x/`** (or select the entry and click *Remove*)
3. Click ***Apply and Close***

As a replacement for the update site for the SVN/Subversion connector SVNKit 1.8 you can use `https://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.8.x/` or/and `https://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.9.x/`.

The automatic update that contacts the update sites can be disabled or configured in *Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Automatic Updates*.

Comment: `https://eclipse.svnkit.com` : `404 Not Found`; `https://svnkit.com` : 200 Ok

Comment: @user8395964 Sure, it is an URL of an Eclipse update site, not an URL of a web site. In this case, Eclipse will read https://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.9.x/site.xml which exists (`200`). `https://svnkit.com` cannot be used as an update site.

Comment: thanks for the link for site.xml - i had both hunches, that the home page can't be used for update site, _and_ that there should exist an api like link somewhere, but i just didn't know where to look for it.

Comment: @user8395964 Note, `site.xml` is for older update sites; p2 update sites will have a `content.jar`, `content.xml`, `compositeContent.jar` or `compositeContent.xml` file instead (see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Composite_Repositories_%28new%29)).